# Lock merge, when rebase is possible - bitbucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-merge

I want to lock merge on pull request, when rebase is possible. Is any way to do it, or force rebase before merge? I can't use `merge check hook`, because is lock by administrator. I use bitbuckt.

Thanks for any help

Comment: what do you mean by "rebase is possible"? To me it seems to be always possible

Comment: rebase is possible, it means we have commits between top of our branch and head of develop